# get current location with runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-play-services

I am a learner in android. I am trying to get weather on current location. There is a "Refresh" button in my app to update the UI with latest weather details. When the app loads, it shows weather of 0.0, 0.0 latitude and longitude. When I click on "Refresh" button, it shows the weather of my current location. How can I get the weather of my current location when the app loads? I have used Google Play Services to get the current location. Below is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public String apiKey;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
    public String forecastUrl;
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    public MainActivity() {
        apiKey = “XXXXXXXXXX";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getForecast();
            }
        });
        getForecast();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void getForecast() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            forecastUrl = “http://www.forecastUrlGoesHere.com/" + apiKey + “/“ + latitude + "," + longitude;
            toggleRefresh();

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(forecastUrl).build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            toggleRefresh();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    updateView(); //updates the screen ui
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            alertUserAboutError();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_error_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void updateView() {
    //code to update ui
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    //check network availability
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    private void toggleRefresh() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, latitude + " " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_location_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, 9000);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed, ERROR: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few ways to get the expected result. Let me write the steps for one of them:

a) Use a ProgressDialog and start it in onCreate

b) Move the getForecast() from onCreate

c) In the onConnected method, once the lat and long are available, check if the ProgressDialog is still visible. If yes, dismiss this dialog and call getForecast

ProgressDialog link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `onConnected` callback, call `getForecast();`:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, latitude + " " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_location_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    getForecast();
}
```